# Why isn't my tilemap collider appearing?

Tags: unity, tilemap, collider

I am trying to make a 2d game but my player falls through the tilemap every time.

My tilemap collider doesn't seem to show up.

What is going on and how do I fix this?

The first image is rigidbody currently falling through the tilemap and the tilemap. The second image is rigidbody currently falling through the tilemap and the rigidbody.
[image: rigidbody currently falling through the tilemap and the tilemap]

[image: rigidbody currently falling through the tilemap and the rigidbody]

Comment: How did you configure collision on the white tile you're using?

Comment: the white block is the tilemap with a tilemap collider and the red square is the rigidbody with a box collider

Comment: That's already stated in your question, and not what I asked. I asked how you configured the collision representation for the individual tile that you've painted into the tile map.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the sprite itself

to fix I clicked the sprite copy that unity creates whenever you first import a sprite
went to collider type and selected grid. this allowed the tilemap collider to work on the white block and any new tiles painted

Comment: That's not a copy of the sprite, that's a tile. The tile references the sprite, but also has other information like collision.